# No such file or directory, python, visual studio code

Tags: python, path

```py
grass_img = pygame.image.load('grass.png').convert()
```

Above script is giving me:  `No such file or directory.` I don't know if it's something with *path*. Because when I do it in *Eclipse* it doesn't give an error. I am in *visual studio* code, `grass.png` is in the same folder, or if I write the full path from *C drive* it's still the same error. Really frustrating. I am new. I added my project folder to the *path*. I really just don't understand *path* / *python path*.

Comment: did you try `c:/full/path/to/grass.png` ? use / instead of \ because \ has special meaning in strings (even in path) like `\n` for new line, `\t` for tab, `\Uxxx` as Unicode (ie. in `c:\Users`)

Comment: different tools may start script with different `Current Working Folder` (which you can check with `os.getcwd()`) and then it search your file in different place then you expect. You should use full path or better you should use `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to get folder with script - and `os.path.join(BASE, 'grass.png')` to get full path to image.

Answer (score 0):

Different tools may start script with different `Current Working Folder` (which you can check with `os.getcwd()`) and then it searchs your file in different place then you expect.

You could use full path to image but better you should use `os.path` to get folder with script

```
BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

and use `os.path` to create full path to image

```
...load( os.path.join(BASE, 'grass.png') )...
```

---

**BTW:**

If you will keep images in subfolder - ie. `resources` - then you can do

```
...load( os.path.join(BASE, 'resources', 'grass.png') )...
```

Comment: Ty, I did this and saw my path was messed up form some reason, lots of reinstall and config later and no issue with a proper path.